# Data sent from ajax as null into the MVC controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I got JS function which use `ajax`. It calls the controller which suppose to get data and parse it. It ssems like on client side data variable formed ok bu the controller gets nothing!

I call JS function like `getTheDiagramm('/PPTDesign/getReceiversDiagram', recIntervalsRec.total, recIntervalsRec.records);`

Here's the function as is

```
 function getTheDiagramm(action_url, total_d, records_d) {

                        var mainData;

                        var table_form = {
                            total: total_d,
                            records: records_d
                        }
                        var postData = JSON.stringify(table_form);

                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: action_url,
                            async: false,
                            data: postData,
                            dataType: "json",
                            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                            success: function (data) {
                                mainData = data;
                            }
                        });

                        return mainData;
                    }
```

On the controller side

```
  public JsonResult getReceiversDiagram(DesignReceiversMap postData)
        {
            List<string> resultData = new List<string>();
            return Json(resultData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        }
```

Models

```
public class Design {
        public int recid;
        public String well;
        public String q1;   
        public String q2; 
        public String down; 
        public String up; 
    }

    public class DesignReceivers : Design {
        public String period1; 
        public String period2;
    }
    public class DesignReceiversMap {
        public int total;
        public List<DesignReceivers> records;
    }
```

So, what it sends
[image: http://i.gyazo.com/d5ef811e0f32e77f29bb4fe1331f9980.png]

and what controller gets
[image: http://i.gyazo.com/660bfd8b3808328d974c1c2b89993249.png]

I really don't understand what's wrong.  Could you help me to fix it, please?

Comment: @MichaelFürstenberg yep, there are screenshot I added

Comment: Yes, I saw that first screenshot about 1 second after I posted the comment. So I removed my comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method `public JsonResult getReceiversDiagram(DesignReceiversMap postData)`
expects DesignReceiversMap object as input. But that's not what you send when you call the method.

Try this in your controller:

```
public JsonResult getReceiversDiagram(string postData)
```

and this in your js:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: action_url,
    async: false,
    data: "postData=" + postData,
    success: function (data) {
        mainData = data;
    }
});
```

then you can parse the data.